# How to load images into uicollectionview cell from url asynchronous

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have a method that I'm calling from cell in the viewForRowAtIndexPath method.

The method containts only this code

```
 NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
            completionBLock(image);
        });
```

Images are loading very slowly and sometimes not at all. Everytime the cell goes back into view the method gets called again.

This is in my cellForIndexPathRow

```
[Method getImage:brochureModel.brochureCoverUrl Oncompletion:^(UIImage *image) {
    cell.imageView.image = image;
}];
```

How can I download images from a url and display it in a collection view reusable cells.

Note: I'm trying to not use any third party libraries for my app

My problem is with the caching of the images. I tried this with self.imageCache being a mutableDictionary.

```
if (self.imageCache[urlString]) {
    UIImage *imageFromCache = self.imageCache[urlString];
    onImageDidLoad(imageFromCache);
} else {
    [API fetchImageFromUrl:urlString onDidLoad:^(UIImage *image) {
        self.imageCache[urlString] = image;
        onImageDidLoad(image);
    }];
}
```

Comment: You should really just use `SDWebImage`, but if you don't want to use any third party libraries download the images with `NSURLSession` and cache the responses.

Comment: I'm using SDWebImage in one of my other projects. This project I'm trying to not use third party libraries. How will I cache it? By saving the image in a dictionary that I can get by the index path? @dan

Comment: Use an `NSURLCache` or an `NSCache` keyed by the image url.